# Windows 2016 won't run .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-server-2016

I have a Java application which uses CMD to execute a .bat file which creates a file after it runs. The script gets executed successfully in windows 2012, but not in windows 2016! I have granted "Log on as a batch job" user right on both Windows Servers.

In win2016:
-If no credential is supplied then the script is run successfully but throws out error that the output file is being used by another process!

-If credential is supplied and if the credential is either domain admin or a local admin, the script does not execute and throws out error 0; also, Windows event log shows cmd error.

-If the credential is supplied as the built-admin, the script is ran successfully without any issue.

What am I missing here?
anyone have any idea?

Comment: What API does this application use exactly?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPO policy for UAC was not configured correctly.  It needs the following:

-User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode – Elevate without prompting

-User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode – Disabled